# python logging lost message after log file is deleted

Tags: python, logging

I'm using `RotatingFileHandler` and `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. Everthing goes fine until I manually deleted the log file.
For example, my log file is wrote to `/path/to/mylog.log`. If this file got deleted or gzipped, python is not able to find it and all later log messages got lost, though all code may seem goes well.

Is there any way can match the follow requests on the same time:

- create log file if file does not exist when app starts. (I know `logging` module has already do this for me)
- if log file is deleted after app starts, create log file again and continue logging without restart app.
- logging rotating still works properly as what `RotatingFileHandler` and `TimedRotatingFileHandler` do.

Thank you for @blues 's answer. I tried his advice and got some code here, not fully tested, but it seems to work.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, WatchedFileHandler, TimedRotatingFileHandler


class WatchedRotatingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler, WatchedFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False):
        RotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, filename=filename, mode='a', maxBytes=maxBytes, backupCount=backupCount, encoding=encoding, delay=delay)
        self.dev, self.ino = -1, -1
        self._statstream()

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            if self.shouldRollover(record):
                self.doRollover()
            # notice reopenIfNeeded() calls os.stat
            # may cause 
            self.reopenIfNeeded()
            logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)


class WatchedTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler, WatchedFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None):
        TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(
            self,
            filename,
            when=when,
            interval=interval,
            backupCount=backupCount,
            encoding=encoding,
            delay=delay,
            utc=utc,
            atTime=atTime
        )
        self.dev, self.ino = -1, -1
        self._statstream()

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            if self.shouldRollover(record):
                self.doRollover()
            # notice that reopenIfNeeded calls os.stat
            # it may cause efficiency issues
            self.reopenIfNeeded()
            logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
```

Comment: Do you have to delete the log file manually?

Comment: In fact, it is gzipped by our Devops team as the file may goes too big, although it's not big at all. They do this for all apps on the server.  @leaf_yakitori

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own Logger class that does this. The FileHandlers assume that once the app has started that the file isn't touched by anything outside the script.

There is a special handler for the case where the file can be deleted/moved while the app is running. It is the `WatchedFileHandler` and it's a version of the `FileHandler` that will reopen/recreate the file if it is gone. There is however no version of this for the rotating handlers.

So you will have to combine the `WatchedFileHandler` and the `RotatingFileHandler` to get the functionality of both.